# How to create a custom permission level for Contribute + editing quick nav + footer nav links in SP Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, navigation, modern-experience, custom-permission-level

In SP Online modern sites, I want to to have a custom permission to be Contribute + the ability to edit those quick nav + footer links on the page. If you can fine tune it to be only the quick nav that is even better.

There is an article on this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/how-to-create-and-edit-permission-levels apparently for SP Online modern sites.

Does anyone know which specific permission to add to grant the nav links updating? We only want that to be included and preferably minimize adding in anything extra.

`Edit` rights grants this, but gives too much control which includes adding or removing lists and apps, and editing columns and views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, SharePoint Online **"EDIT LINKS"** permission: You need the **Manage Lists** permission.

And in fact, there is only difference between **Edit permission level** and **Contribute permission level** is Manage Lists permission.

[image]

It is worth noting that the **Manage Lists** permission includes **create and delete lists, add or remove columns in a list, and add or remove public views of a list**.